# How to speed up image downloads from S3

Tags: ios, swift, image, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My team works on an iOS app that uses S3 and DynamoDB to manage user profile pictures. We have default profile pictures when a user creates an account. When they upload a custom profile picture, we

1. upload the file to S3 and generate a pre-signed URL for that user
2. store the pre-signed URL in DynamoDB in our "users" table

When a user goes to login, we fetch the pre-signed URL from that user and download the image for that user. If the pre-signed URL has expired, we'll generate a new one, replace it in DynamoDB, and download the new image from the new URL.

Images are downloading more slowly as more users create profile pictures. What is the best way to handle this? Should we serve the images through CloudFront instead? We'd like to use security best practices so continuing to use pre-signed URLs is probably necessary here.

*Edit*: All of our users are based in the United States

Comment: What's the point of having a profile picture if only that user can see it? Anyway, storing presigned URLs in a database seems like an anti-pattern. Why not just generate the presigned URL each time it is requested? You could still do presigned URLs with CloudFront if you want, but it is entirely unclear at this point why adding more users has caused profile pictures to display slower. Where is the bottleneck exactly in this process? DynamoDB and S3 should be able to scale without issues.

Comment: On re-read I think I see what you are saying now. All logged in users can see other user's profile pictures? If that's the case then I suggest using CloudFront signed cookies instead of presigned URLs. Signed cookies allow you to restrict content served by CloudFront to only logged in users, without having to generate presigned URLs for each request.

Comment: What @MarkB said. Signed cookies would be the solution to use here.

Comment: @MarkB Appreciate the comment. Users can't see all other user's profile pictures, they connect with one other user and can see that person's profile picture. That's why we're using pre-signed URLs. Not exactly sure why it has slowed down, I've just noticed that it has as we've had more users. Why is storing presigned URLs in a database an anti-pattern?

Comment: You're storing values that are only valid for a temporary time in a database. A cache like Redis seems like a more appropriate storage location for something temporary like that. In any case, you need to do some debugging to figure out where the performance hit is before you can figure out a solution.

Comment: Why store the presigned URL at all?  Signing a S3 object doesn't involve an API request, it should be a fast activity, certainly faster than a database that's getting full of old data.

Comment: Option 1: store image locally on device (in the Documents directory with app data, no in Temp directory, which may get deleted). You can still store it in database for when the user changes a device or wipes the app, but that happens only rarely, so won't be a perf concern.
Option 2: store image directly in the database, base64 encoded and ready for delivery. User logs in and downloads that stored image directly. No additional round trips, and your security concerns are addressed, since this is not a separate S3 storage. 
Both options are of course if you are talking about limited images.